# Is this sentence a simple sentence or a compound sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence, present-tense

> You can either come with me now or walk home.

Some people say it's compound because there are two clauses, but I think there aren't two clauses: there is one subject and a compound verb. Are there two clauses or one sentence, i.e. is this sentence a simple or a compound sentence?

Comment: You are on the right lines. In "You can [either come with me now] [or walk home]", the bracketed elements are verb phrases, not clauses, so this is a 'simple' sentence.

Comment: Thank you BillJ.

Comment: Can someone please answer my burning question? I have to explain this to my students. If they refer the website which says other wiise, I have to insist on my understanding and BillJ's confirmation. Will that be ok?

Comment: Yes, in basic grammar it is a simple sentence. But in **advanced** grammar it would considered a complex sentence because "either come with me now or walk home" would be analysed as a subordinate clause consisting of a coordination of two verb phrases. But are you're students studying advanced grammar?

Comment: My students are learning English at basic level. So the first explanation is sufficient. If any student needs more clarification, I can explain it now. Yet the website said it's a compound sentence. Anyway I am happy with your answer, Thank you once again BillJ.

Comment: In that case, you can confidently tell them that it's a simple sentence containing a single subject, "you",  and a coordination of two verb phrases.

Comment: Yes, a single subject and a coordination of two verb phrases. Thank you.